# Some flexbox outlining problems in my project

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

i had a couple problems with my flexbox project. first of all the nav doesnt fully center 3 items, so the .middle one isnt perfectly centered as you can see.
In the main part i have a OneByOne div, and a aboutOneByOnes. but i dont know how to outline them so they fit correctly. i want it to be outlined as the image below but i cannot get it done as i dont think its a good habit to give fixed values to the aboutOneByOnes div. Heres my code + css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bit-academy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="left">
            <img src="logo_white.png" class="logo" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="nav-item">
                <img src="universe_icon.png" class="icon" alt="">
                <span>Universe</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <img src="reviews_icon.png" class="icon" alt="">
                <span>Reviews</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <img src="feedback_icon.png" class="icon" alt="">
                <span>1:1's</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <img src="doelen_icon.png" class="icon" alt="">
                <span>doelen</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <img src="leaderboard_icon.png" class="icon" alt="">
                <span>leaderboard</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <img src="meer_icon.png" class="icon" alt="">
                <span>meer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="xp"><p>Level 14 - 3 %</p></div>
        
        <div class="nav-right-item">
            <img src="credits_icon.png" class="icon-right" alt="">
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-right-item">
            <img src="profile.png" class="icon-right" alt="">
            <img src="meer_icon.png" class="icon-right" alt="">
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div class="oneOnOne">
            <h1>1:1's</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Coach</th>
                    <th>Gecreëerd</th>
                    <th>Voltooid</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">Bob, de Coach</td>
                    <td class="text">26 minuten geleden</td>
                    <td class="text"></td>
                    <td class="text">Bezig</td>
                    <td class="btn">Vul in</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">Bob, de Coach</td>
                    <td class="text">16 uur geleden</td>
                    <td class="text"></td>
                    <td class="text">Wachten op Coach</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">Mo, Hulpcoach</td>
                    <td class="text">60 dagen geleden</td>
                    <td class="text">42 dagen geleden</td>
                    <td class="text">Afgerond</td>
                    <td class="btn">Bekijk</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="aboutOneOnOne">
            <h2>Over 1:1's</h2>
            <span>Om jouw groei in beeld te krijgen voer je samen met je coac 1-op-1 gesprekken.
                Tijdens een 1:1 gesprek bespreek je samen met je coach je huidige vaardigheden en kies je nieuwe vaardigheden uit om aan te werken. Zo zorgen we samen dat je groeit.
            </span>
            <img src="growth.png" class="growth" alt="">
        </div>   
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono';
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Vertically align items */
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #000563;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logo {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.middle {
    flex: 1; /* Let the middle section take available space */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
    color: white;
}

.right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 10px; /* Add some margin to the right */
}

.nav-item, .nav-right-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    color: white;
}

.profile {
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.icon {
    width: 24px;
}

.icon-right {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    height: 100vh;
}

table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.text, th {
    padding: 1rem;
    
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

.oneOnOne {
    flex-grow: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.aboutOneOnOne {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
}

.growth {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 24vh;
}

.xp {
    color: white;
}

.btn {
    background-color: rgb(80, 173, 76);
}
```

Here is an image of how i want it to be, anyone got an idea on how to fix some of the problems im facing?

I tried using border collapse but that would mean some of my padding disappeared, apart from that i tried to give fixed widths on the aboutOneByOnes, but i think there is a better way im just not seeing as you usually dont want to give fixed px widths. i tried justify-content: center on the parent aswell but that seems to not be working.

Comment: _"so the .middle one isnt perfectly centered as you can see"_ - of course it isn't, because the elements to the left and right of it, don't take the same amount of space. `justify-content: space-between;` distributes the remaining space of the row, equally _between_ the columns.

Comment: Also **don't** ask *multiple* questions at the same time. If you have more than one question, ask them separately.